# How to send dictionary back to Django view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

In my view I have a dictionary of users, i'm passing it to the template inside args{} dictionary(maybe not the proper way to do that).
Then when I POST data on the page with AJAX call I want this dictionary to come back to the view(in order to add new entries to it). How can I send it back using JavaScript, jQuery or AJAX?

If anyone wondering what the hell am I doing:
I'm doing a constructor for model, so customer can search for users and add them to some kind of a group table(picking one by one), but before I can save the model I need to keep track of users customer added. I feel like using a dictionary for this is not a good way, but even if it would be a list or something I still don't know how to keep data back on AJAX calls.

**ADDITION TO ANSWER GIVEN BELOW**
**IF YOU HAVE SIMILAR PROBLEM MAYBE IT IS GOOD TO READ**
I ended up writing everything in one script and note - not in the file, but to the  tag, for some reason the solution and some jquery functions can not work as intended if called from file(weird, I always thought it makes absolutely no difference).
So yeah, if you follow the answer below you will be able to pass dictionary back to Django view, but the stuff that you will pass is not longer a dictionary it is not unicode string. You need to convert it back to dictionary(if you need to use it like dictionary later).
You do it with following code:

```
import ast
received_dict = request.POST['received_dict']
newdict = ast.literal_eval(received_dict)
```

But be careful, try to output the dictionary(that was initially sent) on your page for debugging. For some reason sometimes it may contain ' instead of "  '   ", I believe it happens if you pass it not to  but to .js file(maybe it was other reason, don't remember). So if you have it you would probably need to do this before ast.literal_eval function:

```
received_dict= received_dict.replace("u&#39;", "'") # Maybe you need to delete u also, try for yourself
received_dict = received_dict.replace("&#39;", "'")
```

But I don't use it, it seems to pass everything OK if Javascript is inside  on the page itself.

Also if anyone wonders I had problems with getting values to script from AJAX generated html, jquery couldn't see the ids and stuff. I solved my problem by changing this(use it as template):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        // some stuff
    });
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
          // notice changes
            });
```

I think it is called Event Delegation. You put 'document' as selector, then .on and in the brackets first is the action(can be submit, click or whatever) and where it happened(form, div, etc. probably you can use any selector). Sorry if description is stupid I'm new to jquery.
I hope this helps... multiple ajax requests on one page is pain in the ass :)

Comment: well, why is this on hold? I asked "how to post dictionary to the view" and I got the answer. Do I need to show you how dictionary looks like? or Django template tags? It was not "question seeking debugging", but general question framework and it's co-existence with other languages and techniques. I don't care about the post anymore since I got answer, but you just spoil stuff for guys who are seeking for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have passed dictionary in d from view to template

```
{'d': data_dict}
```

now first store this dictionary d in javascript variable like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var my_data = "{{ d }}"
});
```

And then pass this variable in ajax call in data attribute.

```
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "your url",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{'data_dict':my_data}
                    .......
                  });
```

Let me know this is working or not? LEt me know.
May be you have to use json.stringyfy and json.loads.

Comment: This is what I was thinking about, but ajax throughs error: Uncaught ReferenceError: my_data is not defined. I guess I need to make ajax grab variables from JavaScript somehow. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: var my_data = "{{ d }}"
console.log(my_data)
What it print in console?

Comment: This is the proper way to get django variable in javescript variable.
var my_data = "{{d}}"

Comment: hm... it works(shows it in console), but for some reason it works starting from the second submit... I probably need to pass empty dict on the page creation....might work.  I will tell in a minute :)

Comment: well... it assigns data to my_data, but it doesn't passes my_data to ajax script(still same error, my_data is not defined). I suppose I need to write something to pass it to ajax, since it is in different file

Comment: Both lines are in different file? Write both in same html page or same javascript file to easy use.

Comment: it seems to work(when in the same file, though I would like to make things more separate). It still throws an error inside a view, but that means that I finally got something there :) I will debug it up and figure out details. Then I will write myself some notes in original post and mark your answer :) Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Please dont forget to add notes and accept this as an answer.

Comment: Hey man, I accepted your answer and added a note to the question post :) If you can, maybe edit your answer and write something like "If you have similar problem - read note in the question" in the first line, maybe it will help somebody :) Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "url-of the-view",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{'data_dict':your_dict,}});
```

Then inside your view, you can handle it like:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    data_dict = request.POST.get('data_dict')
```

And you can do whatever processing you want to do on data_dict.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use Django template tags in ajax(since it is in other file and doesn't share variables and Django template processor). It would work if I would find the way to pass variables from my html page JavaScript to AJAX(see other answer)